# ActorSystem.Create() ignores config

Tags: akka.net

I am trying to instantiate an actor system with non-default behaviour (e.g. clustering or remoting) but no matter what I do the `ActorSystem` always ends up with default configuration. The config object and settings object appear correct (e.g. actor.provider == cluster) but the actual run-time object always has defaults.

I've tried constructing the config many different ways. With App.config cdata and by manually parsing a config file with `ConfigurationFactory` and passing it in to Create. I had the problem with 1.4.3 and with 1.3.17.

I downloaded the Akka source code and debugged it. Stepping through the Create method I found that the root `HoconObject`'s items dictionary contains 2 entries with the key "akka". One entry is mine, the other looks like a fallback. The getter method resolves the fallback.

I guess there is some weird string formatting happening...

[image: Debugging the Hocon getter with 2 keys]

[Update] There seems to be confusion about what is actually happening. Here is a screen-shot of what HoconObject looks like when it works:

[image: Debugging the Hocon getter with 1 (overridden) key]

In the screen-shot you can clearly see a *single* entry in the Items dictionary for "akka" that is set to "provider=cluster", which isn't the default and is coming from the config file. The previous screen-shot shows 2 entries, one of which is "provider=cluster" and the other is clearly the default that Akka injects. Both key = "akka". The bug causes Akka to select the default rather than the override.

I understand that Hocon allows overrides from defaults but that isn't what's happening. Again, if you look at the source code for HoconObject you'll see the screen-shot is of a plain .Net dictionary called 'Items' and the TryGetValue is the .Net implementation... not a Hocon implementation.

This is obviously a parsing bug that cases Akka to behave incorrectly and throw no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to post my question as a comment.

Do you have a code I can use to replicate the problem? A code snippet of how you build your config would be fine.

> I downloaded the Akka source code and debugged it. Stepping through the Create method I found that the root HoconObject's items dictionary contains 2 entries with the key "akka". One entry is mine, the other looks like a fallback. The getter method resolves the fallback.

Yes, this is the actual behavior of a `HoconValue`. a `HoconValue` is a list of value fragments that will be converted into a proper data type when you call the appropriate getter function. For example, the `HoconValue` instance that you see in your debug session is actually 2 HoconObject fragments, and the proper merged object can be retrieved by calling the `GetObject()` function of that `HoconValue` instance.

Comment: Yeah.. 'Items' is a .Net dictionary with string keys. It's on HoconObject not HoconValue. HoconValue is what the method returns. It would seem like a very weird use case for a dictionary<string, T> to use invisible characters to distinguish otherwise identical strings.

I tried lots of patterns for using config, then it spontaneously started working, so it's hard to give an example and I don't know what changed. It might be that the file was malformed somehow but the hocon parser gave to error.

Comment: It's not, it's just how HOCON is implemented under the hood, you have to remember to do a `GetObject()` to make sure that you're getting a `HoconObject` and not a `HoconValue`

Comment: It's literally a dictionary:

[link](https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka/Configuration/Hocon/HoconObject.cs)